# How to set default value for the field in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, command-line-interface, default

I have the MongoDB and want to set a default value for the field:-

```
{field1: "default"}
```

I am not using mongoose or any other package, I will access the MongoDB with CLI and python.

How to change the schema and specify a default value in MongoDB using CLI?

Answer (score 1):

This is [not a feature that MongoDB provides](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-24430).